# Using a Pythonesque range() generator function with the Java foreach loop

Tags: java, unit-testing, iterator, interval

Now that we have the nice new `foreach` loop in Java, the old-style loop looks ugly be comparison.

I like the way Python has a `range()` generator that allows the foreach construct to iterate over a range of integers.

I have written a `Range` class which allows this.  Please provide comments.

```
package highland.mark;

import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * A class to enable java's 'foreach' loop to accept a range.
 * <p>
 * This allows replacing the C style:
 * 
 * <pre>
 * <code>
 *      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {...}
 * </code>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * with:
 * 
 * <pre>
 * <code>
 *      for (int i : range(10)) {...}
 * </code>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * Three versions of range() are provided allowing combinations of start, end,
 * and step.
 * 
 * @author Mark Thomas
 * @version 1.0
 */
public final class Range implements Iterator<Integer>, Iterable<Integer> {

    /**
     * The next integer to be returned by the iterator.
     * 
     */
    private int next;
    /**
     * The last integer to be returned will be (next - 1).
     */
    private final int to;
    /**
     * The increment added to the value of next after each iteration.
     */
    private final int step;

    /**
     * A Method to be used with the java 'foreach' loop.
     * <p>
     * Usage:
     * 
     * <pre>
     * <code>
     * import static highland.mark.Range.range;
     * ...
     *      for (int i : range(from, to, step)) {...}
     * </code>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @param from
     *            : int, first value returned.
     * @param to
     *            : int, one more than last value returned.
     * @param step
     *            : int, increment for each iteration (may be negative so long
     *            as <code>(to < step)</code>.
     * @return An Iterable<Integer> which supplies an Iterator<Integer> which,
     *         on each iteration, returns integers from <code>from</code> to
     *         <code>(to - 1)</code> incrementing by <code>step</code> each
     *         time.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if <code>step == 0</code> or <code>step</code> is the wrong
     *             sign.
     */
    public static Iterable<Integer> range(int from, int to, int step)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return new Range(from, to, step);
    }

    /**
     * A Method to be used with the java 'foreach' loop.
     * <p>
     * Usage:
     * 
     * <pre>
     * <code>
     * import static highland.mark.Range.range;
     * ...
     *      for (int i : range(from, to)) {...}
     * </code>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @param from
     *            : int, first value returned.
     * @param to
     *            : int, one more than last value returned.
     * @return An Iterable<Integer> which supplies an Iterator<Integer> which,
     *         on each iteration, returns integers from <code>from</code> to
     *         <code>(to - 1)</code> incrementing by 1 each time.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if <code>(to &lt; from)<code>.
     */
    public static Iterable<Integer> range(int from, int to)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return Range.range(from, to, 1);
    }

    /**
     * A Method to be used with the java 'foreach' loop.
     * <p>
     * Usage:
     * 
     * <pre>
     * <code>
     * import static highland.mark.Range.range;
     * ...
     *      for (int i : range(to)) {...}
     * </code>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @param to
     *            : int, one more than last value returned.
     * @return An Iterable<Integer> which supplies an Iterator<Integer> which,
     *         on each iteration, returns integers from 0 to
     *         <code>(to - 1)</code> incrementing by 1 each time.
     */
    public static Iterable<Integer> range(int to) {
        return Range.range(0, to, 1);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc) private constructor only used by the static range()
     * methods.
     * 
     * @param from : int, first value returned.
     * 
     * @param to : int, one more than last value returned.
     * 
     * @param step : int, increment for each iteration (may be negative so long
     * as (to < step).
     * 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if step == 0 or step is the wrong sign.
     */
    private Range(int from, int to, int step) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (step == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The step argument cannot be zero");
        }
        if ((to - from) / step < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The step argument has the wrong sign");
        }
        this.next = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.step = step;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Iterable#iterator()
     */
    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return this;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.util.Iterator#hasNext()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.step < 0 ? this.to < this.next : this.next < this.to;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.util.Iterator#next()
     */
    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        int value = this.next;
        this.next += this.step;
        return value;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.util.Iterator#remove()
     */
    @Override
    public void remove() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "The iterator returned from range() does not support remove()");
    }
}
```

**Test code (testng):**

```
package highland.mark;

import static highland.mark.Range.range;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class RangeTest {

    @Test
    public void testRangeFullySpecified() {
        String result = "";
        for (int i : range(2, 19, 3)) {
            result += i + " ";
        }
        assertEquals(result, "2 5 8 11 14 17 ");
    }

    @Test
    public void testRangeBackWards() {
        String result = "";
        for (int i : range(19, 2, -3)) {
            result += i + " ";
        }
        assertEquals(result, "19 16 13 10 7 4 ");
    }

    @Test
    public void testRangeDefaultStep() {
        String result = "";
        for (int i : range(2, 9)) {
            result += i + " ";
        }
        assertEquals(result, "2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ");
    }

    @Test
    public void testRangeDefaultStepAndStart() {
        String result = "";
        for (int i : range(7)) {
            result += i + " ";
        }
        assertEquals(result, "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ");
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testwrongWay1() {
        for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") int i : range(2, 19, -3)) {
            // No-op;
        }
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testwrongWay2() {
        for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") int i : range(2, -19, 3)) {
            // No-op;
        }
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testZeroStep1() {
        for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") int i : range(2, 19, 0)) {
            // No-op;
        }
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testZeroStep2() {
        for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") int i : range(2, -19, 0)) {
            // No-op;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While it is tempting to edit and improve your question, it also makes the existing answers look wrong - it invalidates them. [There is a meta post about this here...](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/can-i-edit-my-own-question-to-include-suggested-changes-from-answers). I have rolled-back your edits, but feel free to create a new question with the revised code, or one of the other alternatives suggested in that link.

Comment: The edits contained clear comments indicating the changes and acknowledging the answer that prompted them. I feel it is a shame that you felt it necessary to remove them.

Comment: @HighlandMark: Here is good explanation about the drawbacks (and guides about the suggested ways): http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1482/7076

Comment: You don't need to name your test methods `testFoo` when you use the `@Test` annotation. Also, given that all tests are for the `Range` class, I'd remove it from their names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

+1 to *@rolfl* and some other notes:

1. I like your `final`s and the self-checking unit tests. It's good that they test only one thing, it helps debugging and [defect localization](http://xunitpatterns.com/Goals%20of%20Test%20Automation.html#Defect%20Localization). Keep it up!
2. The code violates the [`Iterator.next()`'s contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29):

   > Throws:
   >
   > `NoSuchElementException` - if the iteration has no more elements

   Consider this:

   ```
   final Iterable<Integer> range = range(1, 3, 1);
   final Iterator<Integer> iterator = range.iterator();
   System.out.println(iterator.next()); // 1
   System.out.println(iterator.next()); // 2
   System.out.println(iterator.next()); // 3, but should throw NoSuchElementException
   ```

   The third `next()` prints `3` instead of `NoSuchElementException`.
3. I'd move some duplication from the test method to a [custom verification method](http://xunitpatterns.com/Custom%20Assertion.html#Verification%20Method):

   ```
   private <T> void verifyRange(final Iterable<T> range, final T... expectedValues) {
       final List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
       for (T value: range) {
           result.add(value);
       }
       assertEquals(Arrays.asList(expectedValues), result);
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   verifyRange(range(2, 19, 3), 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17);
   ```
4. > ```
   > @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
   > public void testwrongWay1() {
   >     for (@SuppressWarnings("unused")
   >     int i: range(2, 19, -3)) {
   >         // No-op;
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

   You don't need the loop nor the `@SuppressWarnings` here, the following is the same:

   ```
   @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
   public void testwrongWay1() {
       range(2, 19, -3);
   }
   ```
5. You could use a better package name than this:

   > ```
   > package highland.mark;
   > ```

   [Java Package Names on c2.com](http://c2.com/ppr/wiki/JavaIdioms/JavaPackageNames.html)
6. This comment is rather unnecessary, I'd remove it:

   > ```
   > /*
   >  * (non-Javadoc)
   >  * 
   >  * @see java.lang.Iterable#iterator()
   >  */
   > @Override
   > public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
   >     return this;
   > }
   > ```

   (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)
7. This is definitely hard to read/understand:

   > ```
   > return this.step < 0 ? this.to < this.next : this.next < this.to;
   > ```

   Consider this:

   ```
   if (this.step < 0) {
       return this.to < this.next;
   } else {
       return this.next < this.to;
   }
   ```

   Or this:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean hasNext() {
       if (step < 0) {
           return to < next;
       } else {
           return next < to;
       }
   }
   ```

   Modern IDEs use highlighting to separate local variables from fields, so you don't have to use `this.` here.
8. > ```
   > /**
   >  * The next integer to be returned by the iterator.
   >  * 
   >  */
   > private int next;
   > /**
   >  * The last integer to be returned will be (next - 1).
   >  */
   > private final int to;
   > /**
   >  * The increment added to the value of next after each iteration.
   >  */
   > private final int step;
   > ```

   A few empty lines between the fields would be readable:

   ```
   /**
    * The next integer to be returned by the iterator.
    */
   private int next;

   /**
    * The last integer to be returned will be (next - 1).
    */
   private final int to;

   /**
    * The increment added to the value of next after each iteration.
    */
   private final int step;
   ```

   Anyway, these comments doesn't say anything which is not already in the code, I'd remove this ones too.

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent on this, and your very helpful feedback.
3. Great refactoring - I'll put that in.

Comment: 2. Lesson learned - when implementing an interface to check for implied contracts. Fixed. 
4. Yes - much better.
5. Noted, but I don't have a domain name, and my email is prone to change.   
6. I agree about noise comments, however, as I am implementing an API these methods become part of the public API for my class - should I have a javadoc comment referring to the interface?  
7. Agreed. The ternary operator does not make for readable code (what possessed me?). Spaces too.

Comment: 5. I see that the recommendation to use the reverse domain name idiom for package names (7.7 Unique Package Names) was moved in the Java Language Specification at Java 7 (to 6.1 Declarations).

Comment: @HighlandMark: #6 is currently not a javadoc comment (starts with `/*` instead of `/**`), that's why I've mentioned it as noise comment. I don't know how javadoc handles public overridden methods without any comment. If it's useful change the comment to a javadoc comment and keep it. If it's same without the comment (javadoc could be smart here, I guess) remove it.

Comment: It turns out that javadoc produces almost the same output if nothing is there!

Comment: @HighlandMark: Cool, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @palacsint Is it just me or there is no 4 ? About #2, if the iterator contain `[1,2,3]` doing 3 `next()` should not throw an execpetion, Am I wrong here ?

Comment: @Marc-Andre: #4: It's there (check the markdown). I guess it's a Google Chrome issue. Feel free to report on Meta :) I don't have time for that now. #2: the upper-bound is not inclusive (check the javadoc of the original code), so I think I'm right here.

Comment: @Marc-Andre: #4: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136019/169573

Comment: My bad, you're right `The last integer to be returned will be (next - 1).`. (Thanks for the link for the bug)

Answer (score 8):

For the most part, this appears to be neat, and well structured.

There is a significant bug, though:

- `Iterable<Integer>` implies an `iterator()` method. Each time you call that `iterator()` method you should get a new instance of an interator, not an 'expired' instance.

For example, the following code should print the numbers 1 to 10 twice....

```
Range onetoten = Range.range(1, 10, 1);

for (Integer i : onetoten) {
    System.out.println(i);
}

for (Integer i : onetoten) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Your code will only print them once.

The fix for this is to store the `from` value as well as the `to` and the `step`, and to then return a duplicate `Range` in the `iterator()` method.

---

EDIT: I should point out this: [`IntStream.rangeClosed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) (Java8)

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I'll make the change you suggest.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the new java.util.stream package.